# Can I use System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener on Windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, tcplistener

I am developing a windows phone application and I need to use the `"System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener"` class but there is no such class when developing for the Windows Phone.

- Can someone suggest to me how can I use it?
- do I need to add some reference or it's not possible at all?

Comment: This class is not accessible in WP. Check this WP+Sockets tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This class is not available on the Windows Phone platform. For a complete list of supported operational socket components, take a look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).